# Cookie with expiration when network connection is terminated

Tags: php, session, networking, cookies, wifi

First of all I would like to set the ground so you can understand the nature of my question. I am currently developing a web application which turns a free hotspot into a paid one. The payment process is hand-by-hand and the end customer receives a coupon with a code generated by the web application. Each voucher code will have an expiration time.

What I would like to do is to, somehow, keep track of the time each code was active on the network so that the end customer can log off, come back and use the network with the time that is left for his voucher code.

I assume this is quite challenging and requires working with the session keeping of the router itself (Mikrotik, Meraki etc) so I would like to know if there is a more "universal" approach to this using a cookie.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried localStorage, this might help you out. you can save the time in localStorage and when the user logs in start with that stored time.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I am thinking of developing a cookie that stores the amount of time that the device is connected to the hotspot but I can't figure out how I could "stop" that timer in the cookie when the user disconnects. Is there some documentation on localStorage as I have never used this technique. Thanks again !

Comment: The problem of saving data into the cookies is that, it might get lost due to lots of reasons like, user didn't allow to save cookies or browse make crash or user clear all the data but, apart from this you can use localStorage which saves your data in browser database. check this link its a simple tutorial hope this will help you out. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, I am going to experiment with this method and see where it goes from there. Have a good day !